# python for loop not working inside a function body

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, data-science

This is my code-

```py
def read_data():
    filename=(r"\School_Project\Data\votes.csv")
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        for data in csvfile: #here data 
            csvfile.seek(0)
            for x in csvfile.readlines():
                return print(x)

read_data()
```

Here the **data** is not iterating i.e. for loop isnt working well inside function body and cannot print all the values in the file only 1st line is being printed
`Please help me out with this error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becaues you use `return print(x)`, you should return each lines of file. For example:

```py
def read_data():
    filename = (r"\School_Project\Data\votes.csv")
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        res = "\n".join(csvfile.readlines())
        print(res)


read_data()
```

Comment: Thanks I got your point!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate through a csv file like this. You will need a library like **csv** or **pandas**.
See for example:

```
import csv

filename = (r"\School_Project\Data\votes.csv")

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in datareader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: yes but the thing is I want it to do in a function body this is my question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `return` there which ends the function -- and thus the loop as well -- after the first iteration.

Also why do you need to iterate over `csvfile`? `.readlines()` already does that for you and gives you back a list of all the lines in the file.

Finally, as @GrowingWings mentioned, avoid processing CSV files manually; use `csv` or `pandas` instead.